# sumar matrices en matlab con for

Tags: matlab

Tengo este ejercicio para sumar 2 matrices en matlab pero no sé muy bien cómo utilizar el ciclo for.

Utilizando la función "input" declara 4 variables que soliciten
(num_filas_A)     número de filas matriz A
(num_columnas_A)  número de columnas matriz A
(num_filas_B)     número de filas matriz B
(num_columnas_B)  número de columnas matriz B

Utilizando la función randi crea las matrices correspondientes
(A y B) según las dimensiones obtenidas en el punto anterior con valores entre 1 y 10.

Utilizando condicionales (if) anidados valida la regla para sumar matrices:

- Primero deberás asegurar que la matriz A y B tienen la misma cantidad
  de filas. De lo contrario, desplegar un mensaje error.
- En caso de cumplir con lo anterior, también deberá cumplir con que
  la cantidad de columnas en A sea igual que en B.
  De lo contrario, desplegar un mensaje error.
- En caso de que cumpla las dos condiciones, recorrer elemento por
  elemento (Aij) y sumarle el elemento correspondiente (Bij)

- PISTA: la función "for" permite hacer un ciclo con el que puedes recorrer todas las filas y/o columnas de la matriz.

```html
num_filas_A=input('Ingrese nuemero de filas en A: ')
num_columnas_A=input('Ingrese numero de columnas en A: ')
num_filas_B= input('Ingrese nuemero de filas en B: ')
num_columnas_B=input('Ingrese numero de columnas en B: ')

A=randi([1,10],num_filas_A,num_columnas_A);
B=randi([1,10],num_filas_B,num_columnas_B);
disp('Matriz A')
disp(A)

disp('Matriz B')
disp(B)


if  num_filas_A ~= num_filas_B
    disp('ERROR: El número de filas de A debe ser igual al de B')
else
    if  num_columnas_A ~= num_columnas_B
        disp('ERROR: El número de columnas de A debe ser igual al de B')
    else
        AB_suma= zeros(num_filas_A,num_columnas_A)

%       for % Agregar parametros
%             for % Agregar parametros
%                 AB_suma() =
%             end
%         end
%         disp('La suma de la matriz A + matriz B es: ')
%         disp(AB_suma)
%     end
% end
```

Comment: y cual es la pregunta, problema/error en especifico?. lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Como ya validaste que ambas matrices tienen el mismo número de filas y columnas podes usar num_filas_A o num_filas_B para el primer for (necesitas 2 for anidados) y num_columnas_A o num_filas_B para las columnas. En mi caso solo voy a utilizar los datos de la primer matriz:

```
num_filas_A = input('Ingrese número de filas en A: ');
num_columnas_A = input('Ingrese número de columnas en A: ');
num_filas_B = input('Ingrese número de filas en B: ');
num_columnas_B = input('Ingrese número de columnas en B: ');

A = randi([1,10], num_filas_A, num_columnas_A);
B = randi([1,10], num_filas_B, num_columnas_B);

disp('Matriz A')
disp(A)
disp('Matriz B')
disp(B)

if num_filas_A ~= num_filas_B
    disp('ERROR: El número de filas de A debe ser igual al de B')
else
    if num_columnas_A ~= num_columnas_B
        disp('ERROR: El número de columnas de A debe ser igual al de B')
    else
        AB_suma = zeros(num_filas_A, num_columnas_A);
        for i = 1:num_filas_A
            for j = 1:num_columnas_A
                AB_suma(i,j) = A(i,j) + B(i,j);
            end
        end
        disp('La suma de la matriz A + matriz B es: ')
        disp(AB_suma)
    end
end
```